# Call the same event handler on mouse click and enter key press

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

Can we use the same event handler which would listen to the mouse click event and the event dispatched when enter key is pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `FlexEvent.ENTER` or `KeyboardEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

Below code may Help You: -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            private function callHandler(event:*):void
            {
                if ( event.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN || event.type == MouseEvent.CLICK)
                { 
                    if (event.type == MouseEvent.CLICK || (event as KeyboardEvent).charCode == 32 )
                    {
                        Alert.show("Clicked", "Alert"); 
                    }

                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button label="Click" x="100" y="100" click="{callHandler(event)}" keyDown="{callHandler(event)}"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: He'll also want to do a nested conditional to test for the enter key. `if ( e.type == KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN || e.type == MouseEvent.CLICK){ if ( ( e as KeyboardEvent).code == 13 || e.type == MouseEvent.CLICK){CODE TO RUN GOES HERE}}`. Also might be worth setting a default value for the event argument of null so that it can be called without an event.